# MutableLiveData<String> to MutableLiveData<Int>

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-jetpack

How could I convert `MutableLiveData< String>` to `MutableLiveData< Int>`.

```
 val text = NonNullMutableLiveData<String>("")
```

My *class NonNullMutableLiveData*:

```
 class NonNullMutableLiveData<T>(private val defaultValue: T) :
        MutableLiveData<T>() {
        override fun getValue(): T {
            return super.getValue() ?: defaultValue
        }
    }
```

I would like to add another `MutableLiveData<Int>` in which I have transformed value of `MutableLiveData<String>`

Thanks

Comment: MutableLiveData<Integer> will work i think

Comment: This question is not clear, what do you mean by convert? You want to take the value in `text` and convert it to an `Integer`? You want to know how to create a `MutableLiveData<Integer>`? You want to know how to map from one `LiveData` to another?

Comment: @MidasLefko I would like to map it to another `MutableLiveData<Int>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `Transformations.map` to get a intLiveData.

```
val intLiveData = Transformations.map(textLiveData) {
    try {
        it.toInt()
    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
        0
    }
}
```

And then `intLiveData.value` may be still null, even if `textLivaData.value` is already "2". Because `intLiveData` will NOT CHANGE untill `intLiveData` was observed and actived.

That means you should set a observer to `intLiveData`, and wait for the observer to start.

```
intLiveData.observe(lifecycleOwner,  Observer{ intValue ->
    // get the int value.
})
```

As [google](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#kotlin) says,

> You can use transformation methods to carry information across the observer's lifecycle. The transformations aren't calculated unless an observer is watching the returned LiveData object. Because the transformations are calculated lazily, lifecycle-related behavior is implicitly passed down without requiring additional explicit calls or dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LiveData [Transformations](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations.html) (specifically [map](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations.html#map(android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData%3CX%3E,%20android.arch.core.util.Function%3CX,%20Y%3E))):

```
LiveData intLiveData = Transformations.map(text, text -> {
      try {
          return Integer.parse(text);
      } catch(NumberFormatException ignored) {
          return 0;
      }
});
```

For Kotlin something like this:

```
val intLiveData = Transformations.map(text) {
        try {
            it.toInt()
        } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
            0
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried Kotlin example. Value in `intLiveData` is all time null. Inside  `val text = NonNullMutableLiveData<String>("")` value changes but not in `intLiveData`
I am using 2-way databinding to EditText.

Comment: The mapping fun above works. Sounds like you have an issue somewhere else, perhaps your databinding is not posting value to your text LiveData? I think that you should try to debug and add some logging  and if you are still stuck ask another question

Comment: It's strange..         
`val a = text.value `,
 `val b = textInt.value` 
value of `a` is 2 and `b` is null. 
I copied Kotlin version of code above for  `textInt`